# UFT to SQL Server conecction which is located at different domain

Tags: sql-server, connectivity

I need to connect to a SQL Server through UFT (Unified Functional Testing) but the problem is SQL Server is present at different domain whereas QTP (HP QuickTest Professional) is present in a different domain.

I am able to connect to SQL Server manually from my domain using

```
runas /netonly /user:mydomain\TestUser 
    "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe
```

Where *mydomain* is the domain in which the SQL Server is present. This is working fine when I connect it manually, but it failed to establish a connection when I tried to connect it through QTP.

Connection string that I'm using:

```
provider=sqloledb.1;server=10.130.15.11,1421;uid=testuser;password=mypassword"
```

The password in the connection string is different from the password that I provide after executing above `runas` command. I also tried with passing both the domains in UID in connection string in QTP but still not able to connect.

Answer (score 2):

The uid & password attributes are used for SQL Server Authentication. You cannot use those connection string values with Windows Authentication. I suspect you are getting login failures with error 18456, state of either 2 or 6. The state portion of the failure message will give you the detailed reason for failure. [This post by Aaron Bertand](https://sqlblog.org/2011/01/14/troubleshooting-error-18456) gives a detailed rundown of most/all possible failure reasons.

If you want to use Windows Authentication to connect to SQL Server from a different domain, you would need to have a [trust](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961481.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) established between the two domains. With the trust established, you would replace the uid & password attributes with `Trusted_Connection=True;`

If your second domain is not trusted, and you cannot establish a trust, then you would need to use SQL Server Authentication instead. You would need to create the SQL Server login, and then your existing connection string format would work.